# How to write a smart generic collection Indexer?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, generics, types

The code below is written in Vb.Net but I accept a C# solution too.

---

I have these classes:

- CommandlineParameter(Of T)

  ```
  Class CommandlineParameter(Of T)
  End Class
  ```
- CommandlineParameter

  ```
  Class CommandlineParameter : Inherits CommandlineParameter(Of Object)
  End Class
  ```
- CommandlineParameterCollection

  ```
  Class CommandlineParameterCollection : Inherits Collection(Of CommandlineParameter)
  End Class
  ```

In the `CommandlineParameterCollection` I added a generic `Add` method:

```
Public Shadows Sub Add(Of T)(ByVal param As CommandlineParameter(Of T))

    If Me.Contains(param.Name) OrElse Me.Contains(param.ShortName) Then
        Throw New ArgumentException(message:="Parameter already exists.", "param")

    Else
        MyBase.Add(param)

    End If

End Sub
```

Then I use it in this way:

```
Dim cmds As New CommandlineParameterCollection
With cmds
    .Add(Of String)(Param1)  ' CommandlineParameter(Of String)
    .Add(Of Boolean)(Param2) ' CommandlineParameter(Of Boolean)
End With
```

Now, the problem is that when I call the Indexer, it returns me a `CommandlineParameter` (`CommandlineParameter(Of Object)`) then I need to specify additionals directcasts around my source-code to specify what type it is, an example:

```
Console.WriteLine(CStr(cmds(Param1).Value))
Console.WriteLine(Cbool(cmds(Param2).Value))
```

Then to avoid this, I tried to specify a generic type Indexer but I discovered that .Net doesn't support this.

So by the moment I have this indexer:

```
Default Public Overloads Property Item(ByVal paramName As String) As CommandlineParameter
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Get
        Return Me.Find(paramName)
    End Get
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Set(ByVal value As CommandlineParameter)
        Me(Me.IndexOf(paramName)) = value
    End Set
End Property
```

What solution exists for this to avoid the additional casts and return a value of the type I want?

I will clarify that the `CommandlineParameter` ( `CommandlineParameter(Of Object)` ) class is not necessary at all, If a solution implies delete it then I can delete it, because I designed it just to make more friendly the usage of that object.

Comment: Your add should just add the generic type. Instead of `.Add(Of String)(Param1) ` it should be `.Add(Of T)(Param1) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Collection<T>` assumes, that every item has the same `T`, you can't store `CommandlineParameter<string>` and `CommandlineParameter<bool>` in the same `Collection<T>`.

IMO, best you can do here is to mimic collection behavior like this:

```
class CommandLineParameter<T> { }
class CommandlineParameterCollection
{
    // use most common type to store items in inner collection - object
    private readonly List<object> inner;

    public void Add<T>(CommandLineParameter<T> value)
    {
        inner.Add(value);
    }

    public void Remove<T>(CommandLineParameter<T> value)
    {
        inner.Remove(value);
    }

    public CommandLineParameter<T> GetAt<T>(int index)
    {
        // will throw InvalidCastException if T at given index doesn't match passed T
        return (CommandLineParameter<T>)inner[index];
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean mimic entire collection behavior - `Add<T>` and `Remove<T>` in my sample allows you to pass different `T` each time you call them - but don't inherit `Collection<T>`. You've got it right - `GetAt` is an indexer replacement.